# Is a git repo as html content safe?

Tags: debian, web-server, git, web-hosting

I've been searching with a couple different terms but didn't find exactly what I was looking for.

I got the idea to start a blog with a flat file CMS. It would be handy to have the pages in a git repository, so I can easily update the blog from anywhere and have it automatically update with [webhook](https://github.com/adnanh/webhook). The question is, could I safely, just clone and pull the changes to the public content on the server? Or should I rather clone it to some un-published folder and copy the files to the public contents?

I think about using [Grav](https://github.com/getgrav/grav) for the CMS, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safe enough. There's CMS systems out there that already do this, such as [Jekyll](https://docs.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll).

Comment: That's kind of where I got the idea from. I'm still not sure if it's good practice to do so though. It's just a hobby project, anyway, but I still don't want to employ bad practice just because it's easy and popular ;-)

Comment: Let me ask you this instead: what negatives do you see to it that would make it not a good practice?

Comment: Thinking about it like that I can't see any particular reason. It just feels weird to have a quasi public folder directly linked to a repository. It's a gut-feeling I'd say.